# What makes mercury vapors so harmful?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety, toxicity

I just read an experiment in which mercury has to be heated and in the same experiment there was a note warning not to inhale [mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28element%29) vapors as they are very harmful.

I just can't get the point that why are mercury vapors harmful.

Comment: Did you read wikipedia article on mercury poisoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercury poisoning (also known as hydrargyria or mercurialism) is type of metal poisoning and a medical condition caused by exposure to mercury or its compounds. Mercury (chemical symbol $\ce{Hg}$) is a heavy metal occurring in several forms, all of which can produce toxic effects in high enough doses. Its zero oxidation state $\ce{Hg^0}$ exists as vapour or as liquid metal, its mercurous state $\ce{Hg2^{2+}}$ exists as inorganic salts, and its mercuric state $\ce{Hg^{2+}}$ may form either inorganic salts or organo-mercury compounds; the three groups vary in effects. Toxic effects include damage to the brain, kidneys and lungs.

Mercury poisoning can result in several diseases, including [acrodynia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrodynia) (pink disease) and [Minamata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minamata_disease) disease.

source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)

Comment: @agharehanabbas Please do not copy a source verbatim without quoting the text and without a proper citation.  Plagiarism will not be tolerated.

Comment: ok i wil look at it on my further posts

Comment: You can edit your answer to include a reference.

Comment: @jonsca i have edited my answer and added my source to it